# SSR with Lerna + React + Styled components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styled-components, server-side-rendering, lerna

I trying to build project using Lerna and its `hoist` feature. Everything worked great, before i decided to move ui components from `site` to `packages`, for reuse purposes.

I have file structure like this

```
root
├── node_modules
└── packages
    ├── admin
    ├── site
    └── ui
```

where `ui` is `react + styled-components` components library, and it used as dependency in `site`

```
// site packages.json
...,
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "@root/ui": "^1.0.0"
}
```

`ui` have only one file `index.tsx`

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const SharedComponent: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>Hello from SharedComponent</Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper= styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

export default SharedComponent;
```

then i use tsc to compile tsx

trying to use it inside `site`

```
import React, { FC  } from 'react';
import SharedComponentfrom '@root/ui/dist';

const App: FC = () => {
    return (
            <>
                <SharedComponent />
                <div>Hello from Site App</div>
            </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

So if i start devServer everything is OK.

[image]

But when i try to SSR, i got server side error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

i tried to declare `alias` property in `wepback` settings as mentioned here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14257#issuecomment-508808246

```
// site webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...,
  resolve: {
    ...,
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('../../node_modules/react') // path to root node_modules
    }
  },
}
```

but error is still in present

Also, if i remove `styled-components` from `ui` it works fine. It's seems like the problem is somewhere in `styled-components`

So, how can i pair `lerna` + `styled-components` + `react` + `SSR` ?

Comment: My best guess is that your custom `ui` library and this setup have conflicting React versions.

Comment: @serraosays thanks for reply. As i mentioned, the problem is occured only if i use `styled-components`. If there is only `react` inside `ui`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it work. All i need to do is set `externals` field in webpack config. like this:

```
externals: [
        nodeExternals(),
        nodeExternals({ additionalModuleDirs: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules')] }),
        'express'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use dangerouseInnerHtml to solve css probleum. otherwise if you use emtion.css then you can try @emotion/server
2. try to use next/dynamic or React.lazy to load dynamic
3. I still confused duplicate React.  how to resolve this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).